# How do I construct a LazyTransformer in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

PyTorch has many useful `Lazy*` layers e.g. `LazyLinear` (see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html), but doesn't appear to have a `LazyTransformer`. How can I implement one?

Similar questions for `TransformerEncoderLayer` and `TransformerDecoderLayer`